# Linear Layout with image and Text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have to create layout that have one image and multiple textview and rating like this and i have add a line on inflating this layout with adapter

```
| Image| Name of Product            |
|       Desc                        |
|       Amount                      |
|       EMI details                 |
|       Rating Sybmol total Rating  |
```

So i have tried to create a layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:text="Micromax Canvas Spark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But i am confused how i can create the layout please help me in this

Comment: Do you want he image to he left and the textViews to the right?

Comment: @EugeneH yes and line for each row in the list view when i am infalting it in the list view

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean by line.

Comment: A divider between each list item?

Comment: @EugeneH yes divider in each list item

Comment: Have a look at what I posted.  Is that what you are looking to accomplish?

Comment: Could you post a sample image of what you wish to achieve.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I am assuming you are trying to accomplish.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Micromax Canvas Spark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Micromax Canvas Spark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Micromax Canvas Spark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Micromax Canvas Spark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:rating="2"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text="1003 Votes"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Divider for ListView**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#fff"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

**Update**

Changing the size of the rating bar.

```
 style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
 style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"  // Perfect Size but stars are blue
```

Comment: how can we show the rating star or rating symbol  in this layout

Comment: exactly i was trying but i need also to showing rating symbols to this

Comment: Updating the layout with a rating bar

Comment: @Gaurav Updated the answer with a rating bar

Comment: can't we reduce the size of rating bar i was trying but it is not working and after rating i want show total number of rating

Comment: add style of rating bar : style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall" in RatingBar widget.

Comment: i need to show total number of ratings after the rating bar please update the same also

Comment: You could add a textview for total number of rating next to rating bar widget ? Rating bar and textview put in a horizontal linear layout

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu You are right lol.  For some reason it doesn't pull up an error.  It usually lets me slide without out adding it.  I will update it now. :)

Comment: @Gaurav No Problem.  Good luck with the rest of the project.

Comment: @EugeneH please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527657/listview-with-a-diffrent-number-of-textview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
I have implemented based on your prototype.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Name of Product:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_name_of_Product"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="---" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Desc:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_desc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="---" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="AMT:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_amount"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="---" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="EMI Details:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_emi_detais"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="---" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleX="0.5"
            android:scaleY="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but we need to add total number of rating after rating bar ??

Comment: Then you can add    android:numStars="8"    attribute inside the Ratingbar.

Comment: no i have to show a text view with some details for the ratings after the rating bar